# JXPath to filter SOAP message

Tags: java, soap, xpath, jxpath

I'm trying to extract the value of the node GoodEmail from a SOAP response. It seems that no matter what I try, I always get a org.apache.commons.jxpath.JXPathNotFoundException.

SOAP response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
      <VerifyEmailResponse xmlns="http://ws.cdyne.com/">
         <VerifyEmailResult>
            <ResponseText>Invalid Email Address</ResponseText>
            <ResponseCode>0</ResponseCode>
            <LastMailServer/>
            <GoodEmail>false</GoodEmail>
         </VerifyEmailResult>
      </VerifyEmailResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The Java code:

```
String payload = message.getPayloadAsString(); //The SOAP response
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db =  dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(payload));

Document doc = db.parse(is);
JXPathContext context = JXPathContext.newContext(doc);
String jxpathReply = (String) context.getValue("//soap:Envelope/soap:Body/VerifyEmailResponse/VerifyEmailResult/GoodEmail");
```

To me it seems that the error code suggest that it is the xpath filter that is wrong. I've tried a few different, but can't get it right. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the most FAQ in XPath**. Search for `"xpath default namespace"` and you'll find many good answers.

**A brief explanation** is that in XPath any unprefixed name is considered to belong to "no namespace". Therefore, if we want to specify the names of elements that belong to some namespace (including a default namesopace), these names *must* be prefixed and the prefix specified must be associated (using the particular XPath engine API) withthe namespace-uri of the namespace, in which the particular node resides.

**Therefore, the expression could be something like this**:

```
/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/x:VerifyEmailResponse/x:VerifyEmailResult/x:GoodEmail
```

where the prefix `"x"` is associated (by "registering" this namespace association) with the namespace `"http://ws.cdyne.com/"`